# How to filter a data frame based on user input

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe like below

```
Id,CTY,Types,isOpen,seats
1,BNG,school,true,100
2,HYD,school,true,150
3,MUM,school,true,200
4,BNG,restaurant,false,1000
5,HYD,restaurant,true,1500
6,MUM,restaurant,false,500
7,BNG,hospital,true,700
8,HYD,hospital,true,300
9,MUM,hospital,true,1000
10,BNG,school,false,200
11,HYD,restaurant,true,50
12,MUM,hospital,true,900
```

I would like to filter it based on user input from the command line.

Consider user input could be in any of the below formats

```
1,BNG:school
2,HYD:school,restaurant
3.BNG:school | HYD:school,restaurant
```

Suppose

- if I pass BNG:school as argument all the rows with CTY=BNG and Types=school should be removed.
- if I pass HYD:school,restaurant as argument all the rows with CTY=HYD and Types in (school,restaurant) should be removed.
- if pass BNG:school | HYD:school,restaurant as argument all the rows with CTY=BNG and Types=school, CTY=HYD and Types in (school,restaurant) Should be removed.

How it can be done in a generalized way which handles all kind of below user input. Please help me with this problem.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: please provide your funding and what you have done till now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import spark.implicits._

val sourceDF = Seq(
  (1,"BNG","school",true,100),
  (2,"HYD","school",true,150),
  (3,"MUM","school",true,200),
  (4,"BNG","restaurant",false,1000),
  (5,"HYD","restaurant",true,1500),
  (6,"MUM","restaurant",false,500),
  (7,"BNG","hospital",true,700),
  (8,"HYD","hospital",true,300),
  (9,"MUM","hospital",true,1000),
  (10,"BNG","school",false,200),
  (11,"HYD","restaurant",true,50),
  (12,"MUM","hospital",true,900)
).toDF("Id","CTY","Types","isOpen","seats")

sourceDF.show(false)
//  +---+---+----------+------+-----+
//  |Id |CTY|Types     |isOpen|seats|
//  +---+---+----------+------+-----+
//  |1  |BNG|school    |true  |100  |
//  |2  |HYD|school    |true  |150  |
//  |3  |MUM|school    |true  |200  |
//  |4  |BNG|restaurant|false |1000 |
//  |5  |HYD|restaurant|true  |1500 |
//  |6  |MUM|restaurant|false |500  |
//  |7  |BNG|hospital  |true  |700  |
//  |8  |HYD|hospital  |true  |300  |
//  |9  |MUM|hospital  |true  |1000 |
//  |10 |BNG|school    |false |200  |
//  |11 |HYD|restaurant|true  |50   |
//  |12 |MUM|hospital  |true  |900  |
//  +---+---+----------+------+-----+

val arg =  "BNG:school | HYD:school,restaurant" // "BNG:school" // "HYD:school,restaurant"  // "BNG:school | HYD:school,restaurant"

val p = if (arg == "") Array.empty[String] else  arg.split(""" \| """)

val resFilter = p.size match {
  case 2 => {
    val p1 = p(0).split(":")
    val p2 = p(1).split(":")
    val fltrTmp = (!'CTY.equalTo(p1(0)) && !'Types.isin(p1(1).split(", ").toList:_*)) && (!'CTY.equalTo(p2(0)) && !'Types.isin(p2(1).split(", ").toList:_*))
    fltrTmp
  }
  case 1 => {
    val p1 = p(0).split(":")
    val fltrTmp = !'CTY.equalTo(p1(0)) && !'Types.isin(p1(1).split(", ").toList: _*)
    fltrTmp
  }
  case _ => 'Id > 0
}

println(s"resFilter: $resFilter")

val resDF = sourceDF.filter(resFilter)

resDF.show(false)
//  +---+---+----------+------+-----+
//  |Id |CTY|Types     |isOpen|seats|
//  +---+---+----------+------+-----+
//  |6  |MUM|restaurant|false |500  |
//  |9  |MUM|hospital  |true  |1000 |
//  |12 |MUM|hospital  |true  |900  |
//  +---+---+----------+------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks for your response ..It helped me lot . However Case 1 is not returning desired results..Made few changes and worked fine Thanks!